# Can someone explain why my powershell script does not list all running services but only the first one?

Tags: powershell

The Variable $services lists all the Running Services but why doesn't the Write-Output iterate and present all the running services except the first object?

thanks

```
$Services = get-service | Where-Object {$_.StartType -eq 'Automatic'} | Foreach-Object {
            $Service = @(
                "Name=`"$($_.Name)`""
                "DisplayName=`"$($_.DisplayName)`""
                "Status=`"$($_.Status)`""
            )
        }
        
Write-Output ($Service -join " ")
```

The Variable $services lists all the Running Services but why doesn't the Write-Output iterate and present all the running services except the first object?

Answer (score 3):

The assignment to `$Service` in your `ForEach-Object` is incorrect, it shouldn't be there. With your current code, **`$service` holds the last iterated object**.

The next issue is a typo in the `Write-Output` statement, *which as aside is not needed*, you're using `$service` instead of `$services`. Additionally, you probably want to `-join` with a [new line character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-7.0) instead of a space `' '`.

```bash
$Services = Get-Service |
    Where-Object StartType -EQ Automatic |
    ForEach-Object {
        @(
            "Name=`"$($_.Name)`""
            "DisplayName=`"$($_.DisplayName)`""
            "Status=`"$($_.Status)`""
            '' # An empty string here helps to differentiate each object
        )
    }

$Services -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
```

---

Worth noting, if your intention is export this output, then this is not the right approach. PowerShell already provides built-in cmdlets for transformation into structured data formats, for example, [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

```bash
Get-Service |
    Where-Object StartType -EQ Automatic |
    Select-Object Name, DisplayName, Status |
    Export-Csv path\to\csv.csv
```

---

From feedback in comments, it seems that the desired output are separated Json objects, in which case the code from above can be re-used with a minor tweak:

```bash
Get-Service |
    Where-Object StartType -EQ Automatic |
    Select-Object Name, DisplayName, Status |
    ForEach-Object { $_ | ConvertTo-Json -Compress }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response - the output i'd like is:

    
    Name="AdobeARMservice" DisplayName="Adobe Acrobat Update Service" Status="Running"   

Name="AudioEndpointBuilder" DisplayName="Windows Audio Endpoint Builder" Status="Running"   

Name="Audiosrv" DisplayName=
"Windows Audio" Status="Running"   Name="BFE" DisplayName="Base Filtering Engine" Status="Running"

Comment: Name="AdobeARMservice" DisplayName="Adobe Acrobat Update Service" Status="Running"

Comment: Name="AudioEndpointBuilder" DisplayName="Windows Audio Endpoint Builder" Status="Running"

Comment: Name="Audiosrv" DisplayName=
"Windows Audio" Status="Running"   Name="BFE" DisplayName="Base Filtering Engine" Status="Running"

Comment: each 3 objects joined on a separate line

Comment: Alternatively could i output them as json like so ..

{"Status":4,"DisplayName":"Background Intelligent Transfer Service","service":"BITS"}

Thanks

Comment: If you have additional information you should add it to your question - NOT as comments! ☝

Comment: @Esky73 there is nothing stopping you from changing `Export-Csv` to `ConvertTo-Json` in the last example

Comment: The ConvertTo-Json .. just gives me an unusable Json blob as opposed to singular events like.. {"Status":4,"DisplayName":"Background Intelligent Transfer Service","service":"BITS"}

Comment: @Esky73 see my update

Comment: Thankyou that works :)